# Building gem, executable not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm in the process of writing my first ruby gem and I'm a little new at the whole structure of setting up gems. My understanding from reading [this guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) is that in order to create an executable for my gem I need to do the following:

1. Add a line to my gemspec specifiying the name of the executable like this:

   `s.executables << 'gemname'`
2. Build the gem with

   `gem build gemname.gemspec`
3. Install the gem locally (if you try to install by pushing to rubygems each time you'll end up having to change versions constantly) with

   `gem install gemname-0.0.1.pre.gem`
4. Then test it out with

   `gemname foo-arguments, --bar-options`

If I go through all these steps then on #4 I get the following error:

```
$ gemname
zsh: command not found: gemname
```

Assuming that the executable a file starting with a shebang and located at gemname/bin/gemname

Everything works just fine if I navigate to the root of the gem folder and run bin/gemname to test out the executable.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/2670c55aef93c723a9b6) is a gist of my current gemspec and the gem source is available on github [here](https://www.github.com/smcabrera/get_freaky).

Comment: So, where is the problem??

Comment: Seems to work okay for me (well I get a load error, I think you need to add `commander` to your dependencies). What error do you get – is it some form of “command not found” from your shell? If so you might need to make sure you have Rubygems set up correctly so that the gem executables are on your path. Do other gems work ok?

Comment: @maxd Ah sorry, the problem was that the last bit ```gemname foo-arguments``` doesn't work because it says there is no executable by that name. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @matt I edited the post to include the error I got. I also just noticed that I get this message:
```rbenv: cannot rehash: /home/stephen/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exists
Successfully installed get_freaky-0.1.2.pre```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add all the files that need be included with the gem in `spec.files`. You missed to add the files that you have in the `bin` directory.

For example, I have the following configuration from [one of my gems](https://github.com/arturoherrero/yarr):

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.files         = Dir["{bin,lib}/**/*", "LICENSE", "README.md"]
  spec.test_files    = Dir["spec/**/*"]
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
  spec.executables   = ["yarr"]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your gemspec is trying to change the load path. I would suggest fixing that first, because what you're reporting seems to be consistent with a gem not being able to find its files.

Look at your gemspec for this code:

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
```

Then see http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/

"Gems should not change the $LOAD_PATH variable. RubyGems manages this for you. Code like this should not be necessary ..."

See http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/ for various solutions to load using the existing load path, and helpers such as `require_relative`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you need to ensure your executable is, well, executable.

```
$ chmod a+x bin/gemname
```

Otherwise the command won't be available after building the gem.