# My executable ruby gems don't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I followed this tutorial http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem to figure out how to create ruby gems but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create an executable.

I originally thought I was making a mistake in my own code but the actual gem created with the tutorial itself doesn't seem to work as I expected.  So I'll base my question around the actual gem from the tutorial itself.

If you bundle the exact gem from the tutorial (the gem is named `hola`) into a rails application and try to use the executable command `hola`, all you get are error messages:

```
$ rails hola spanish
# => Error: Command 'hola' not recognized

$ ruby hola spanish
# => ruby: No such file or directory -- hola (LoadError)

$ hola spanish
# => -bash: hola: command not found
```

Even if I attempt to execute the command this way it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ ruby -Ilib ./bin/hola spanish
# => ruby: No such file or directory -- ./bin/hola (LoadError)
```

The only time this seems to execute anything is when I'm inside the actual gem directory recreated by hand in the tutorial and type this:

```
$ ruby -Ilib ./bin/hola spanish
# => hola mundo
```

But this is useless because the whole point of creating an executable is to be able to execute it within an actual project not the gem directory (ie: someone downloading your gem and being able to use it with a single executable keyword, like `rake routes` which then does something).

Can I bundle the `hola` gem from this official rubygems.org tutorial and use it as an executable in the way I was expecting to execute it, like this:

```
$ hola spanish
# => hola mundo
```

If this is possible, how is it done?

Comment: What does your `.gemspec` file look like?

Comment: `bundle exec hola` doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried installing the built gem using `gem install`? Looking at the errors, it seems like the gem wasn't installed on the system or it can't find the executable in your gem path.

Comment: `./bin/hola` is a relative path. Only way that will ever work is from the gem directory. No shell that I know of will try to look up the executable from your `$PATH`.

Comment: @CodeGnome `bundle exec hola` returns `bundler: command not found: hola
Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'`

Comment: @Armando Yes, I have installed the hola gem, it's in my gem list.  It still does not produce an actual executable that works as I would expect it to.

Comment: @matt the hola gem is available here: https://rubygems.org/gems/hola

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I found that this question ended up being a duplicate of:

[Building gem, executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219169/building-gem-executable-not-found)

The solution to make this work is to edit the section in the .gemspec that reads:

```
s.files = ["lib/hola.rb", "lib/hola/translator.rb"]
```

and change it to:

```
s.files = Dir["{bin,lib}/**/*"]
```

Now when I type the command it works perfectly, like this:

```
$ hola spanish
# => hola mundo

$ hola english
# => hello world
```